# jQuery .focus() callback is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus

I just don't get it, why this way of .focus callback is not working?

```
$('a.focus').click(function(){
    $('form input:first').focus(function(){
        console.log('done focus');         
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SHxbj/

anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just do it this way:

```
$('a.focus').click(function() {
    $('form input:first').focus();
});
$('form input:first').focus(function() {
    console.log('focused');
});​
```

The first chunk binds the click on the link to focus the cursor in the input field and the second chunk binds the focus event on the input field and sends the message to the console.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SHxbj/2/)**.

Comment: this ways its just gonna focus on load which is not an objective.

Comment: No it doesn't. Did you try the jsFiddle? The focus call on the input is a bind, not a fire.

Comment: @Alex by that logic, the code would also fire a click on the anchor at load, but that doesn't happen. (That logic is wrong; this answer is correct.)

Comment: Ok, sorry did not see that. That looks awesome so far, this way we detect the focus event and call what is needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('form input:first').focus(function(){
    console.log('done focus');         
});
```

That block of code is binding an event to the first form input, not executing the focus callback when the link is clicked. Your code works as expected, just not the way you are probably thinking. Try clicking the link, and then clicking the first input.

You are probably wanting this:

```
$('form input:first').focus();
console.log('done focus');
```

Comment: Well, my idea is to click the link first, then do the focus and call the callback after focus is done. Any workaround?

Comment: the problem is that I dont want to focus on page load. Only after link been clicked. You click the link, auto scroll up to the form and focus. That simple.

Comment: You still leave those last two lines wrapped in `$('a.focus').click(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Your code binds the callback to the `focus` event, but does not actually focus the element. You can keep it as a callback and manually focus the element, or you can simply fire it after the focus:

Edited; thanks @GNi33 for pointing out the repeat-binding!

```
var $input = $('form input:first');
$input.focus(function(){
    console.log('done focus');         
});

$('a.focus').click(function(){
    $input.focus();
});
```

Comment: but this way you are binding a `focus` - handler everytime the link gets clicked. i would bind it seperated from the click-handler

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.focus').click(function(){
    $('form input:first').focus(function(){
        console.log('done focus');         
    }).focus();
});  
​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/SHxbj/3/)